# How to selectively alternate between DHCP and Static IP from Network Dialog, Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet, dhcp, netplan

I desire to be able to connect LapTop EtherNet port to either a DHCP router **OR** a static IP 3D Printer.

I have a EtherNet connected 3D printer, to which I have a CAT5 cable directly connected between the printer and a LapTop running Ubuntu 20.04.  I desire to be able to selectively alternate between a DHCP selection and a static IP selection from the upper right corner, drop-down-dialog, without having to reconfigure NetPlan. I would disconnect the cable from the LapTop to plug in a cable from my router so that I can connect the LapTop to the InterNet after selecting DHCP in the dialog.

Both the 3D printer and the LapTop auto-negotiates cable 'crossover'.

Is this possible?

thanks in advance, drwho

================

Comment: Most Ubuntu Desktop users don't have dhcp/static configured in Netplan...because they have NetworkManager. This is exactly the kind of use case that NetworkManager has handled well for many years.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that in xubuntu 20.04, but it did not work properly in that OS, I fiddled around quite a bit could not get NetworkManager to work properly. I could only cause static-IP to work by modifying the NetPlan file, and then DHCP stopped working. I moved over to Ubuntu 20.04, and it did not work here, but I made a mistake, which I realized this morning and it is working correctly now. I can select between DHCP and StaticIP through the dialog box. Thanks for your reply.  - drwho

Answer (score 0):

@user535733

Thanks, I had tried that in xubuntu 20.04, but it did not work properly in that OS, I fiddled around quite a bit could not get NetworkManager to work properly. I could only cause static-IP to work by modifying the NetPlan file, and then DHCP stopped working. I moved over to Ubuntu 20.04, and it did not work here either, so I asked the question here in AskUbuntu.

I made a mistake in the dialog configurator, which I realized this morning and it is working correctly now. I can select between DHCP (named 'InterNet') and StaticIP (named 3D_Printer') via the dialog box.

Thanks for your reply. - drwho